# Validate acess token of Facebook + Twitter + Instagram

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

In my app a user can login or register with Facebook, Twitter or Instagram. Fetching and validating access token are done in application (Android and iOS). Now when they send a request for registration, I need to validate the access tokens. Do I have to validate each access token manually like:

```
facebook_data = HTTParty.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me", query: {
  access_token: params[:access_token]
}).parsed_response

# You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
@user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(facebook_data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Facebook I would recommend Koala: https://github.com/arsduo/koala

For Twitter: https://github.com/sferik/twitter

For Instagram this is the official Library: https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem

Comment: Be aware - the Instagram ruby gem is currently not being maintained (as mentioned in the readme)

Answer (score 4):

I had to write custom method,(In case any one needs it):

```
  # Validates fb token
  def self.validate_facebook_token token
    status = false
    begin
      @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
      status = true if @graph.get_object("me")
    ensure
      return status
    end
  end

  # Validates fb twitter
  def self.validate_twitter_token token, secret
    status = false
    client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new(
      consumer_key: APP_CONFIG["TWITTER_CUSTOMER_KEY"],
      consumer_secret: APP_CONFIG["TWITTER_CUSTOMER_SECRET"],
      token: token,
      secret: secret
    )
    status = true if client.authorized?
    return status
  end

  # validates instagram token
  def self.validate_instagram_token token, provider_id
    status = false
    instagram_reponse = HTTParty.get("#{APP_CONFIG['INSTAGRAM_URL']}/users/#{provider_id}", query: {
      access_token: token
    }).parsed_response
    status = true if instagram_reponse['meta'].present? && instagram_reponse['meta']['code'] == 200
    return status
  end
```

Gems used:

```
gem 'koala'
gem 'twitter_oauth'
gem 'httparty'
```

Do let me know if you have a better one.